# How to create a composite of existing components in JSF?

Tags: jsf, components, facelets

I'd like to know if it's possible to compose my own component (or call it Widget, Object).

I mean, instead of (for example) using `h:panelGroup` and a `h:outputLabel` inside it, make my own `h:panelMarkzzz`, as a composition of panelGroup and outputLabel.

Is it possible on JSF?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to create a composition of existing components like that.

Kickoff example:

`/resources/foo/group.xhtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="label" type="java.lang.String" required="true" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
         <h:panelGroup>
             <h:outputLabel value="#{cc.attrs.label}" />
             <cc:insertChildren />
         </h:panelGroup>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

`/test.xhtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:foo="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/foo">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <foo:group label="Label value">
            <h:outputText value="This will appear after label inside the panelgroup" />
        </foo:group>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The `/foo` folder name is free to your taste and you can reference it in XML namespace as `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/XXX`. The XHTML filename is the tag name.

That said, composite components have performance implications and they should only be used when the functional requirement is not achievable using a simple include or tagfile. In your specific case, you'd better use a tagfile instead. A composite component is only worthy when you actually need it for the `<cc:interface componentType="...">`.

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269)
- [Our composite component wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info)
- [JSF `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite` tag documentation](https://javaserverfaces.github.io/docs/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/cc/tld-summary.html)
- [Java EE 7 tutorial - Composite components](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets005.htm)
- [Java EE 7 tutorial - Advanced composite components](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-advanced-cc.htm#GKHXA)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you mean [Composite Components](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/true_abstraction_composite_ui_components1)?