# Can I use HTML5 with Java as backing beans?

Tags: java, html, user-interface, graph, dictionary

I want to show moving objects (vehicles) in a map (road network). I have done the model part in Java using graph theory (vertices + edges). Now what I want is to move a vehicle along a road. But I don't have a clear idea, what should I use to draw the map, and move objects on top of it?

My vehicle objects contain which vertex they are at that moment.

HTML5-SVG and canvas support to draw objects but I couldn't find a way to link Java beans with HTML5.

Can I do this using HTML5? If not what should I do?

Comment: Are there any requirements that the user view this in a browser?  or can you give them a jar to run?

Comment: You can expose your Java models via a REST service and consume that in an HTML5 UI. Sure.

Answer (score 0):

JavaServer Faces 2 [can utilize HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5) as a view technology; combined with AJAX (and maybe a Javascript library like jQuery, Prototype, dojo, etc.), and probably some [third party support](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu-1010/) for the HTML 5 canvas element as a JSF component, you might be able to achieve what you're looking for (I see you have experience with IceFaces, so JSF is something you're familiar with, right?).

Mind you, I've never *tried* JSF and HTML5 myself, but it's worth a shot!

As far as using the HTML 5 canvas element itself goes, I'm afraid I won't be much help in that regard.

**Also worth looking at:**

[JSF HTML5 tag tutorials / guides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252821/jsf-html5-tag-tutorials-guides)

Comment: One more thing, If I select google maps then I can move vehicles on top of that. But then I think I have to use google API? So in that case will I be able to do that with my backing beans?